# Threading with Random wrong result

Tags: python-3.x

When using threading with random.shuffle get wrong result from a list.
There are values missing and other duplicated.

Tried use numpy but get the same problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -tt

import random
from threading import Thread

class Th(Thread):
  def __init__ (self, num, c):
   Thread.__init__(self)
   self.c = c
   self.num = num

  def run(self):
   random.shuffle(self.c)
   for self.i in self.c:
    print (str(self.num) + ' - ' + self.i)


def main():

 with open ('file.txt', 'rU') as cmddb:
    c =  [ cmd.strip() for cmd in cmddb]
 cmddb.close()
 print ('ref:')
 for i in c:
  print (i)

 print ('----')


 thread_number=0
 for i in range(0,5):
  thread = Th(thread_number,c)
  thread.start()
  thread_number += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

#################################3
Result:
file.txt:
ref:
10
20
----
0 - 20     <========
1 - 10
1 - 20
0 - 20     <========= duplicated  / missimg 10
3 - 20   <=
3 - 20   <= again
4 - 10
2 - 10
4 - 20
2 - 20
```

Problem occur some times. Other times it run ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the list c is the same list for all threads. So in some cases, some thread prints the first element of c, for example 10, and before it prints the second element, another thread called shuffle on c. if the order of the values in c has changed, the second element is now 10, so it will be printed again. To avoid it, give every thread a different copy of c:

change: `thread = Th(thread_number,c)` to `thread = Th(thread_number, c[:])`